# Generate all setter in PHPStorm when transforming array to object

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, phpstorm, getter

Often I have to create an object from a parsed csv or other file. These object have lots of fields. So I create a class with alot of variables and the generate the getters and setters.

Then I write a parsing function, something like:

```
public function parseCsvArrayToObject($csvArray){
  foreach($csvArray as $csvLine){
    $object = new $objectType();
    $object->setFirst($csvLine[0]);
    $object->setSecond($csvLine[1]);
    $object->setThird($csvLine[2]);
    ....
  }
}
```

Is there a way to just print out all setters for this class, it is a tedious job, if there isn't, that's fine, but if there is that would be genius.

Answer (score 0):

I think, what you are asking for is not possible.

But you can build your classes in a way, that you don't need the setters and getters for each field individually.

You could just implement the magic __get() and __set(). With them you need to access the fields by name $object->first;

If you like the setters and getters you can implement the magic __call() and react according to the function name passed. This way you have $object->getFirst();

Rough example:

```
public function __call($name, $arguments)
{
    if (substr($name, 0, 3) == 'get') {
        $field = lcfirst(str_replace('get', '', $name));
        if (isset($this->$field)) {
            return $this->$field;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe late, but may help people come along like me:

You can write a small script that generates the classes including the parsing methods you need.